# Scala regular expression : matching a long unicode Devanagari pattern fails

Tags: regex, scala, unicode

Consider the following script code:
import scala.util.matching.Regex

```
val VIRAMA = "्"
val consonantNonVowelPattern = s"(म|त|य)([^$VIRAMA])".r
// val consonantNonVowelPattern = s"(थ|ठ|छ|स|ब|घ|ण|ट|ज|ग|न|ष|भ|ळ|ढ|ख|श|प|ह|ध|ङ|म|झ|ड|ल|व|र|फ|क|द|च|ञ|त|य)([^$VIRAMA])".r
var output = "असय रामः "
output = consonantNonVowelPattern.replaceAllIn(output, _ match {
  case consonantNonVowelPattern(consonant, followingCharacter) =>
    consonant + VIRAMA + "a" + followingCharacter
})
println("After virAma addition: " + output.mkString("-"))
```

It produces the following correct output:
`After virAma addition: अ-स-य-्-a- -र-ा-म-्-a-ः-`

However, if I use the longer pattern (commented out above), I  get the following wrong output:
`After virAma addition: अ-स-्-a-य- -र-्-a-ा-म-्-a-ः-`

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `(?=[^$VIRAMA])` instead of `([^$VIRAMA])` or something similar? The regular expression consumes the group identified by `followingCharacter`, the lookahead group doesn’t. I’m not sure whether that would fix it…it’s just a guess…

Comment: This issue, that "all" means "all non-overlapping", resulted in this doc for `findAllIn` but not `replaceAllIn`. The advice is as in the other comment. http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/2.11.x/api/2.11.x/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex@findAllIn(source:CharSequence):scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is thanks to Lalit Pant-

I'm assuming that the correct output for the second case is:
अ-स-्-a-य-्-a- -र-्-a-ा-म-्-a-ः-

If that's the case, read on. If not, tell me the expected output.

The problem appears to be that with your bigger 'consonantNonVowelPattern', the presence of 'सय' in 'output' makes 'य' show up as a 'followingCharacter' in your pattern match after the 'स' consonant.  'य' is consequently never reported as a consonant.